# How to remove a black background from an image and make that transparent using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using "PerspectiveTransform" method to transform the image in a given rectangle. Method "warpPerspective" works fine, but the output contains the black background and I want to remove the black color and make that transparent.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img2 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\map.jpg")
input_quad = np.float32([[0,0],[1024,0],[1024,752],[0,752]])
output_quad = np.float32([[4,139],[500,137],[500,650],[159,636]])
lambda_img = np.zeros((728, 992,3), np.uint8)
lambda_img[:,:,:] = 255
lambda_val = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform( input_quad, output_quad )
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img2,lambda_val,(992,728),lambda_img, cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)
cv2.imwrite("Valchanged.png",dst)

[enter image description here][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Below is the output I have revived.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your input image is in `.jpg` format so you need to convert the input image from `BGR` domain to `BGRA` domain:

```
img2 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\map.jpg")
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
```

Also you don't need to define a new `lambda_img` on your side, `cv2.warpPerspective` returns a numpy array after applying the transformation.

```
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, lambda_val, (992,728), flags = cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue = [0, 0, 0, 0])
```

When you define `borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT`, you also need to define a `borderValue` which gets filled along the borders, in this case it is black color with 0 alpha value i.e. Transparent or `"#00000000"`